# While installing laravel it's occurred error like getadderinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: laravel

Downloading https://getcomposer.org/version [image]it's error while downloading the laravel globally if there is version issue or anything else please suggest the the any command for help this as well as it's genrate error while update the composer its the any composer problem or else ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to missing Curl on your machine.

**Install CURL:**

Open a terminal window and execute the following command:

```
sudo apt install curl
```

To confirm that CURL is installed correctly, run:

```
curl -V
```

Note: If this is already installed on your device, remove it and install again. To remove the curl:

```
sudo apt-get remove curl
```

If you use purge options along with auto remove, will be removed everything regarding the package, It's really useful when you want to reinstall again.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove curl
```

---

**Additional Considerations:**

If the issue persists, you might need to install the PHP CURL extension. Try:

```
sudo apt install php-curl
```

Hope this will works for you.

If you're working with a Laravel project, you can use Composer to manage dependencies. Create a new Laravel project using:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

For more information visit official [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#creating-a-laravel-project)